# Create a query to database from the data in form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My code

```
#model.py
class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='FIO', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    history_contract = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

#form.py
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    history_contract = forms.CharField(label='History', max_length=100)
    category = forms.CharField(label='Category', max_length=100)

#view
def get_personal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']#data from form
            history = form.cleaned_data['history_contract']#data from form
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']#//data from form
            query = Sotrudniki.objects.filter(fio__contain=name, history_contract__contain=history, category__contain=category)#The part I want to accomplish

    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'personal.html', {'form': form, 'query': query})
```

I need to check the data that I entered into the form. After making a request to the database and returning only the data that I indicated in the form. I got an error at the end "local variable 'query' referenced before assignment", maybe I have a wrong approach to the task. How can I implement the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple logic error. `query` does not exist when the form is not a POST, but you try and send it to the template anyway. You can fix this by putting `query = None` at the beginning of the function.